what happened to free speech?
Mi yodeya is an amazing site. however, it's extremely annoying how these mods monitor it like a hawk. With only some types of questions about certain subjects. who cares if someone asks a question that was asked 7 years ago? or is written without great punctuation. just because it's a question about Judaism that the mods don't like doesn't mean it should be deleted. for all of you who will read this message before the mods delete it remember that this is a communist site!

This is true about all stack exchange sites. Not just Mi yodeya. Try asking a pro Israel question on politics on stack exchange and see how quick the question will be closed. If they don't threaten to block you altogether.

@Schmerel questions on Politics.SE aren't supposed to be Pro anyone, only answers there can advocate a position. But this isn't the place to discuss policies of Politics.SE

Virtually all questions on Politics.SE  about Israel  clearly imply or explicitly accuse wrongdoing on Israel's part. Anything that doesn't is considered pro Israel . Even if there is no mention or reference to Israel  in the question like "why doesn't the ICC try Assad for the use of chemical weapons"

I’m voting to close this question because this is a screed and engages in name calling.

How is it that an amazing site and communist site could be named in one paragraph?

@YDJ apparently, the OP is a communist!

You've been here for two months and have one question under your belt. What basis have you for your accusation?

@Harel13 1- this is actually my 2nd account 2- maybe I only have 1 question because the other ones got deleted!

@YDJ think of this site as a pizza store with great pizza but you can't support Biden in it. It's amazing and republican.

Why do you have two accounts?

@Harel13 what's the problem does it go against the terms and condition of mi yodeya?

I don't know. Seems a bit underhanded, though. Like protesting while wearing a mask.

@Harel13 it's not like you know my other account

If your other account is better-known, then other members would know your standing in the community and recognize whether your grievances have any legitimacy. But right now it just looks like you popped out of nowhere. This is almost a random hit-and-run post. The least you could have done was bring examples of questions that you thought were closed unfairly.

If your sensitive please ignore my insults,but my point is enough with the structure. #anarchism .

@Deskchair anarchy is available at https://www.quora.com/ and effectively at http://www.needaneitzah.com/ Please enjoy!

@DoubleAA thanks for the references.

False Downvotes on my answers
This site does not protect against false downvotes. I have been getting useless hate downvotes on all my answers or questions. There should be a way to cancel those and ban those desperate, insecure haters from the site. Check my latest perfect answer which got immediate 2 downvotes. This site is very biased against anyone who disagree with their traditional sectarian mode of thinking. Also, a guy got pissed in comments for my use of baptism instead of immersion/bath.
Why wait eight days to remove the orloh (foreskin) given that it is considered מאוס (repulsive)?

How is calling your Rabbinic sect of Judaism a "traditional sect" hateful? Is it a not openly known that this site allows only Rabbinic school/sect of Judaism in the broad name of Judaism SE? I have only received hate and false votes here and fearlessly faced the haters.

I downvoted because your answer blatantly misrepresents the text you quote, and when the mistake was pointed out in the comments you refused to acknowledge it

There was no mistake pointed out in the comments, but only rants of hatred and denial. They can disagree all they want, but hateful and insecurity with false downvotes should not be allowed here. There should be some level of impartiality or justice maintained in moderation.

A comment saying (correctly) that the claim you attributed to the text is completely absent from the text you quoted, and that the source you quoted explicitly says the opposite of what you attribute to the text, is indeed a "mistake pointed out," and is not a "rant of hatred and denial"

Show me the proof of anyone showing the source saying opposite of my interpretation. It's a dispute of interpretation, not actual words in quotes. My opponents think birth is impure but not child itself, as if separating the blood of Niddah with the Niddah woman. Anyway the mods still have decency that they haven't banned me, though I was banned from making topic or still banned from making topics

@deuteronomy kindly make the topic on those 3 verses describing the unclean status of everyone born of a woman. I won't make it bec it will be downvoted

"Show me the proof of anyone showing the source saying opposite of my interpretation" - here (quoting from the same verse in section 8)

Thanks I didn't notice that. I will edit the answer to add the ancient views, bec that commentary is apparently Rabbinic later Judaism.
